# Why are non-gray colors used when rendering gray letters?

Tags: image-processing

Why is the left of these better than the right? Is it called something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Why does anti-aliasing in black characters use colors other than gray-scale?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/930/why-does-anti-aliasing-in-black-characters-use-colors-other-than-gray-scale) on the GraphicDesign site.

Words to look up are "anti-aliasing" and ["sub-pixel rendering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering):

> [Subpixel rendering] takes advantage of the fact that each pixel on a colour LCD is actually composed of individual red, green, and blue or other color subpixels to anti-alias text with greater detail or to increase the resolution of all image types on layouts which are specifically designed to be compatible with subpixel rendering.